# Surrogate Keys using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, data-warehouse

We are having event based framework where we use Kafka and Spark streaming and finally persist the data in database. I come from data warehousing world. I would like to use the surrogate keys generated for some of the dimensional data that we are using. How is it usually achieved in spark world? Is surrogate key a relevant topic in the modern big data architecture? Where can I get good information on the shift from data warehousing to big data architecture and how we do data models in big data architecture?

Answer (score 1):

While surrogate keys are not common in "modern big data architecture" there are still use cases for them.  Surrogate keys can still simplify the queries of business intelligence use cases such as Slowly Changing Dimensions.  This is more important if you are migrating an existing data warehousing architecture with business users and tools to a new big data pipeline architecture while trying to maintain the same business tools and processes where the existing system uses surrogate keys.

Whether it is a good idea depends on your use case and actual architecture.

I don't use surrogate keys for developers.  There is value still, but not worth the complexity of a surrogate key pipeline.  Instead of persisting surrogate keys all that logic can usually be done on the fly at query time with enough processing power / longer queries.

Surrogate keys have many uses.  Perhaps I have not covered your use case.  If so, tell us more about what you goal is in using surrogate keys.  I am very interested to hear about what others have done as well.